# Is there an algebraic function that satisfies the Abelian complex multiplication with even irrational multiplicator?

Tags: complex-numbers, algebraic-curves, class-field-theory, elliptic-integrals

According to Abel's astonishing paper "RECHERCHES SUR LES FONCTIONS ELLIPTIQUES.[1]", we can get
\begin{align*}
\varphi_3(x,\kappa_3)&=\frac{x\cdot\left(\sqrt{3}-\,\kappa_3x^{2}\right)}{1+\sqrt{3}\,\kappa_3x^{2}}\\
\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\left(1+\kappa_3^{2}t^{2}\right)}}
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{\varphi_3(x,\kappa_3)}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{\left(1+t^{2}\right)\left(1-\kappa_3^{2}t^{2}\right)}}\\
\Big(\left|x\right|&\leqslant2-\sqrt{3}\Big)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\varphi_5(x,\kappa_5)&=\frac{x\cdot\left(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{10+10\sqrt{5}}\,\kappa_5x^{2}+\,\kappa_5^{2}x^{4}\right)}{1+\sqrt{10+10\sqrt{5}}\,\kappa_5x^{2}+\sqrt{5}\,\kappa_5^{2}x^{4}}\\
\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\left(1+\kappa_5^{2}t^{2}\right)}}
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\int_{0}^{\varphi_5(x,\kappa_5)}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{\left(1+t^{2}\right)\left(1-\kappa_5^{2}t^{2}\right)}}\\
\Big(\left|x\right|&\leqslant\,l_5\Big),
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\kappa_1&=1=\frac{\sqrt{1-k_1^2}}{k_1}\\
\kappa_3&=2+\sqrt{3}=\frac{\sqrt{1-k_3^2}}{k_3}\\
\kappa_5&=2+\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-k_5^2}}{k_5}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
l_5&=\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{\sqrt{10+10\sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{\sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{5\sqrt{5}}}{2\left(2+\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}\right)}}}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt{10+10\sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{\sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{5\sqrt{5}}}{2\left(2+\sqrt{5}-2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}\right)}}}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left(2+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{25+10 \sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{30+14 \sqrt{5}+2 \sqrt{425+190 \sqrt{5}}}\right)
\end{align*}
It is worth noting that these moduli are related to the singular values of elliptic integrals[2].

> My confusion is as follows, whether there is an algebraic function $\varphi_2(x,\kappa_2)$
> (rational function, irrational function can be) and the corresponding
> modulus, satisfying the following equation?
> \begin{align*}
>  \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\left(1+\kappa_2^{2}t^{2}\right)}}
>  =\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\varphi_2(x,\kappa_2)}\frac{\mathrm{d}t} 
>  {\sqrt{\left(1+t^{2}\right)\left(1-\kappa_2^{2}t^{2}\right)}}
>  \end{align*}
> If it exists, how to find it?

[1] Abel N.-H. (1828) Recherches sur les fonctions elliptiques (suite du Mémoire n°9). Cr. [Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik. Journal de Crelle. Berlin.] 3, 160-187.
https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0003?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B189%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D

[2] Katsuya Miyake. COMPLEX MULTIPLICATION IN THE SENSE OF ABEL[C] NUMBER THEORY: Plowing and Starring Through High Wave Forms: Proceedings of the 7th China–Japan Seminar. 2015: 145-167.

[3] Umeno Ken. Theory of Complex Multiplication as a Cradle of Exactly Solvable Chaos[J]. Bulletin of the Japan Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (in Japanese), 2022, 32(4): 221-234.
https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/bjsiam/32/4/32_221/_pdf

[4] Katsuya Miyake. Origin of class field theory (number theory and its applications)[J]. RIMS Kôkyûroku, 1998, 1060: 185-209.
[https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1060-21.pdf](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1060-21.pdf)

[5] Takase Masahito. Three Aspects of the Theory of Complex Multiplication[J]. The Intersection of History and Mathematics, 1994: 91-108.